# Replace a string once another string has been found

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk

I'm programmatically building boxes, but I need to update a .repo file for PHP which has the following contents:

```
# Repository: http://rpms.remirepo.net/
# Blog:       http://blog.remirepo.net/
# Forum:      http://forum.remirepo.net/

[remi]
name=Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/remi/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/remi/mirror
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php55]
name=Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php55/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php55/mirror
# NOTICE: common dependencies are in "remi-safe"
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php56]
name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/php56/mirror
# NOTICE: common dependencies are in "remi-safe"
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-test]
name=Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/test/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/test/mirror
# WARNING: If you enable this repository, you must also enable "remi"
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-debuginfo]
name=Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/debug-remi/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php55-debuginfo]
name=Remi's PHP 5.5 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/debug-php55/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-php56-debuginfo]
name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/debug-php56/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi

[remi-test-debuginfo]
name=Remi's test RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - debuginfo
baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/debug-test/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

I would only like to enable PHP 5.6, so I need to find the string `[remi-php56]`, and then the first instance of `enabled=0` and change it to `enabled=1`.

I'm sure there is a `sed` or `awk` for this, but I have been unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e '/\[remi-php56\]/,/^\[/s/enabled=0/enabled=1/' /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo
```

for process all `.repo` files, or you can specify single target `.repo` file.

Or you can use [you-config-manager](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-config-manager.1.html) to permanent enable/disable repo by name, if `yum-utils` packaje is installed in your systems.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Even if this can probably be solved by a sed command, it would be simpler to use the proper command to change yum configuration:

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
```

And notice, this is explained in the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions.